# Renaming of files and content within files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

Can somebody please support for renaming of files and content within files using Powershell:

- Root folder contains files (xml, txt and others), also subfolders are contained that themselves contain files
- All occurrences of a certain wording in all contained files in all subfolders should be renamed
- Additional requirements:

  - "abc" in the example may also be in capital letters or even mixed (e.g. "ABC", "Abc")
  - Additionally, the file name shall be renamed. This works: `ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace 'uvw', 'xyz' }`. What needs to be added to also cover capital and/or mixed letters? And how to include this in the script below to rename all files in all subfolders in one go?

Tried a bit around including other parameters on the basis of other posts on the topic here but stumbled on access denied issues and others. It only worked - excluding the extra requirements mentioned - when providing the individual subfolders for `$filePath` using the following script. Please advice for making it work for the requirements mentioned:

```
$filePath = "C:\root_folder"
Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_ | ForEach  { $_ -creplace 'abc_123', 'def_123' }) |
     Set-Content $_
}
```

Comment: Try to use regex:
`$_ -replace '[Uu][Vv][Ww]', 'xyz'`
The script will ignore capitalization.

Comment: @Re1ter, PowerShell operators that support string operations are case-insensitive by default, including `-replace`, so no effort is needed for case-insensitive matching (conversely, if you _want_ case-sensitivity, use the `-creplace` variant). If you wanted to control case-sensitivity _as part of your regex_, you could use inline option `(?i)`; place it at the start to cover the entire regex, or - to make _parts_ of the regex case-sensitive - place it as needed, and turn it back off with `(?-i)`. In short: `$_ -replace 'uvw', 'xyz'` is the simpler equivalent of `$_ -creplace '(?i)uvw', 'xyz'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **PowerShell [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators)** that support string operations are **case-insensitive by default**, including [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), so no extra effort is needed for case-insensitive matching: `'uVw' -match 'uvw'` is `$true`, for example.

  - You would only use the `-creplace` variant if you explicitly want case-sensitivity (the `c` prefix, which can also applied to other operators such as `-match` (`-cmatch`) and `-eq` (`-ceq`), indicates case-sensitivity).
- If you want to **process only *files*** in a recursive [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call, add the **`-File` switch**.

  - By default, *directories* are included in the enumeration, and attempting a [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call on a directory results in an 'Access denied' error in *Windows PowerShell* (the error message has since been improved in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

---

Therefore, you're probably looking for something like the following:

- **Caveats**:

  - In your attempt you process *all* files in your directory tree; while trying to rename files to their existing name is a benign no-op (if the string to replace isn't found), unconditionally rewriting the content of files based on a `-replace` operation will corrupt *non-text* files, and with *text* files can change their *character encoding*.
  - Therefore, it's best to:

    - Limit processing to file types of interest, as indicated by their extensions, by adding, e.g., `-Include *.txt, *.xml` to the `Get-ChildItem` call, as shown below.
    - Use an explicit `-Encoding` argument to control the output character encoding.
    - Additionally, you may want to rewrite the files only if an actual string replacement was performed.
  - While the `-replace` operations *match* case-insensitively, the *replacement* strings are used as-is; e.g. `'-ABC-' -replace 'abc', 'def'` results in `'-def-'`.

    - [Your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77089279/45375) is about also *case-matching* the replacement text *based on the matched text*, so that the result in the above example would be `'-DEF-'`

```
$filePath = "C:\root_folder"
$include = '*.txt', '*.xml' # adapt as needed
Get-ChildItem -File $filePath -Recurse -Include $include | 
  Rename-Item -WhatIf -PassThru -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'uvw', 'xyz' } |
  ForEach-Object {
     # NOTE: You may have to use an -Encoding argument here to ensure
     #       the desired character encoding.
     ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace 'abc_123', 'def_123' |
       Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for catching the `Rename-Object` typo, @jennab - fixed. As for making the case of the replacement string the same as what was matched: I don't think there's anything built in, but it's an interesting problem, and I encourage you to create a new question focused just on that. (Feel free to ping me here once you have done so).